# Save all console.log output into a file in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to save all console logs in to seperate file while during debugging/remote debugging

Is that possible?

Comment: You may be looking for this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-filesystem

Comment: no, i want just sniff the logs inside app

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`react-native-xlog`](https://github.com/EngsShi/react-native-xlog)

Wechat's Xlog framework for RN.

You can send log to Xlog, and manager Xlog lifecycle. Handle js/native crash log in production builds.

> attention: you will see the crash log only when you restart your app

**Usage**

```js
import Xlog from 'react-native-xlog';

Xlog.verbose('tag', 'log');
Xlog.debug('tag', 'log');
Xlog.info('tag', 'log');
Xlog.warn('tag', 'log');
Xlog.error('tag', 'log');
Xlog.fatal('tag', 'log');
```

**Decode log file**
Use this [script](https://github.com/Tencent/mars/blob/master/mars/log/crypt/decode_mars_nocrypt_log_file.py) to decode log file:

```
python decode_mars_log_file.py ~/Downloads/log/myapp_20170723.xlog
```